# Basic Cisco VLAN Config

Tags: cisco

Hello very helpful people!!!

Have a stock Cisco 3500XL, haven't worked on Ciscos in forever, does anyone have a sample config for what I need to accomplish? Few notes, the uplink is port FastEthernet 0/24. I need all ports on the switch to be on VLAN 20 and the uplink to be assigned ip 10.10.25.10 with being on VLAN 10 but being "tagged" also on VLAN 20 so data flows.

Comment: what version of software is it running? Do you want traffic on fa0/24 to egress the switch untagged on vlan 10 and tagged on vlan 20, fa0/24 is a trunk port? And perhaps would this be better on Server fault.

Comment: Yes to the egressing the switch untagged on vlan 10 and tagged on 20. fa0/24 is not currently a trunk port. If no response I will move to serverfault. thanks.

Comment: do you need the switch to route? and are you running an L3 image?

Comment: You really need to peruse the documentation for your switch and at least *try* to get the thing configured yourself.  If you have specific problemswe can try to help you with them, but we can't configure your switch for you...

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has pointed out that this is an L2 only switch and cannot route traffic.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff. Good point. Hey, Doon! This is an L2-only switch and cannot route traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no vtp, etc.:

```
vlan 10
vlan 20
int range FastEthernet0/0 - 23
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan 20
int FastEthernet0/24
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20
int vlan10
  ip address 10.10.25.10 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Don't forget to set a default gateway if you utilize other subnets behind an upstream router.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff: a gateway wasn't part of the specification :p

Comment: Neither was setting passwords, but he really ought to do that too.

Comment: Pshaw! It's an internal network, you can trust everybody.